# In Python, split a file into lines, and then print only ones starting with

Tags: python, string, startswith

So, I have a file, for example, 'test.txt'. I want to check and print only the lines starting with 'result':

**test.txt** looks like this:

```
this is a test file
used to test a python script
result 1
dummy text goes here
result is nice
blah blah blah
the end
```

Then, what i want is for the print only output like this:

```
result 1
result is nice
```

I'm having difficulties trying to figure this one out, because apparently i can't use startswith() function, since when i split the file it becomes a list, here's the code I last tried:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as text:
     lines=text.readlines()
     for x in lines:
          if lines[x].startswith('result'):
               print(lines[x])
```

And that gets me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
if lines[x].startswith('result'):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What can I do instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x` **is** your line not an index to it. To get the line and the index use `enumerate()` but in this case you don't need it. Just use `x` rather than `lines[x]`

Comment: `for x in lines` iterates over each item in the list. In this case, `x` is one line in your file and not the index. You can do the following: `if x.startswith('result'): print(x)`

Comment: oh lmao, i'm feeling dumb now, it worked, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use `lines=text.readlines()` before the loop. Eliminate that line and just have `for x in text: if x.startswith('result'): print(x)` There is no need to have the entire file in memory if you are just using one line at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop you created, all the lines are already assigned to the lines list, and you assign them to the variable x sequentially with the loop. That's why you can access it directly using x when accessing it inside the loop.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as text:
    lines = text.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        if x.startswith('result'):
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your loop this way:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f_in:
     for line in f_in:
          if line.startswith('result'):
               print(line.rstrip())
```

Alternatively, you can write a filter if you want to keep all the lines in question:

```
with open('test.txt') as f_in:
    those_lines=[line.rstrip() for line in f_in if line.startswith('result')]
    # all the lines in question...
```

Or you can modify the first loop to keep the lines in question:

```
those_lines=[]
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f_in:
     for line in f_in:
          if line.startswith('result'):
               those_lines.append(line.rstrip())
```

Then if you want to print them:

```
print('\n'.join(those_lines))
```

The code:

```
lines=text.readlines()
```

reads the entire file into a list. This is not necessary since you are only printing single lines and testing single lines. It is more idiomatic Python to loop over the file line by line in this case.

Comment: that's nice, i thought readlines() would split the file into lines, and not that the loop itself could go line by line. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lines in a loop directly. You don't need to use `readlines()` here. Please find the code below can be helpful.

```py
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("result"):
                print(line)
```